# Java Socket Timeout Exception with Tomcat 7 and Axis 2

Tags: java, tomcat, soap, axis, socket-timeout-exception

We have a Tomcat 7 and Axis 2 for our Java SOAP web service. We also use C3PO connection pooling (also in other web services which works fine). The web service works for about two days and after that time period it is not working anymore. Then our consuming customer receives a Java Socket Read Timeout Exception. After restarting the Tomcat servlet everything works fine again. Processing the request has a duration of about 3 seconds. The Axis 2 has a default socket timeout of 30 seconds. Our customer has a wait timeout of 60 seconds. The strange thing about the problem is that it´s working for amount of time and then the problem occurs.

I don´t know which kind of code I can show here to find the problem. What causes the socket timeout here?

Answer (score 0):

### Reason of Socket Timeout:

Socket timeouts can occur when attempting to connect to a remote server, or during communication, especially long-lived ones.

They can be caused by any connectivity problem on the network, such as:

1. A network partition preventing the two machines from communicating.
2. The remote machine crashing. This cannot easily be distinguished
   from a network partitioning.
3. A change in the firewall settings of one of the machines preventing
   communication.
4. The settings are wrong and the client is trying to talk to the wrong
   machine, one that is not on the network. That could be an error in
   Hadoop configuration files, or an entry in the DNS tables or the
   /etc/hosts file.
5. If its over a long-haul network (i.e. out of cluster), it may be a
   transient failure due to the network playing up.
6. If using a client of an object store such as the Amazon S3 and
   OpenStack clients, socket timeouts may be caused by
   remote-throttling of client requests: your program is making too
   many PUT/DELETE requests and is being deliberately blocked by the
   far end. This is most likely to happen when creating many small
   files, or performing bulk deletes (e.g. deleting a directory with
   many child entries). It can also arise from a transient failure of
   the long-haul link.

Comparing this exception to the [ConnectionRefused](https://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/ConnectionRefused) error, the latter indicates there is a server at the far end, but no program running on it can receive inbound connections on the chosen port. A Socket Timeout usually means that there is something there, but it or the network are not working right

### Identifying and Fixing Socket Timeouts

The root cause of a Socket Timeout is a connectivity failure between the machines, so try the usual process

1. Check the settings: is this the machine you really wanted to talk
   to?
2. From the machine that is raising the exception, can you resolve the
   hostname.
3. Is that resolved hostname the correct one?
4. Can you ping the remote host?
5. Is the target machine running the relevant Hadoop processes?
6. Can you telnet to the target host and port?
7. Can you telnet to the target host and port from any other machine?
8. On the target machine, can you telnet to the port using localhost as
   the hostname. If this works but external network connections time
   out, it's usually a firewall issue.
9. If it is a remote object store: is the address correct? Does it go
   away when you repeat the operation? Does it only happen on bulk
   operations? If the latter, it's probably due to throttling at the
   far end.

### Resource Link:

[Socket Timeout Details](https://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/SocketTimeout)